# how to provide parameter for subreport in JasperReport correctly

Tags: java, jasper-reports, subreport

I have a report template that has a subreport;
in main report I have some parameters that should be available in subreport too.
Main report parameter is defined like this:

```
<parameter name="PID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
```

And in subreport I defined same parameter with the same name:

```
<parameter name="PID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
```

And I provided parameters of master report for sub report like this:  \

```
     <subreport>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="50"/>
            <parametersMapExpression>
                 new HashMap($P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP})
            </parametersMapExpression>
            <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
            <subreportExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["subRPT.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
     </subreport>
```

but this throws this:

```
SEVERE: null
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Incompatible java.lang.Integer value assigned to parameter PID in the subRPT dataset.
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.prepare(JRFillSubreport.java:711)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.prepareElements(JRFillElementContainer.java:329)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:419)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:378)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2035)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:760)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:270)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:128)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:946)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:845)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:58)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:417)
    at biorec.control.reporting$1.doInBackground(reporting.java:177)
```

What is the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thnak you all,
But the problem was in version miss-matching between my JasperReport library and iReport.
using same versions fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

First save subreport JRXML in Jasper server then save same subreport in desktop which you want to use and then drag Subreport element from palette .

Step 1:-

```
    Select "Use an existing report" option and select the same subreport
```

next

```
     it will ask for database, if you are using the same database
```

then click Next button

```
    then it will ask for parameters , select all the parameter expression
```

and next

```
  choose "Store the directory name in  a parameter" option
```

then finish .

Now select the subreport then go to the property tab and  It won't run in Ireport  and select "Subreport Expression" , there you have to give the path of your subreport which is in Jasperserver in this

```
 format "repo:/path_of_subreport in jasper".
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<subreportParameter name="PID">
    <subreportParameterExpression>
        <![CDATA[$P{PID}]]> 
    </subreportParameterExpression>
</subreportParameter>
```